# jackson map serialization, custom serializer for the key do not invoked

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to have functional which allow me to serialize `Map<CustomType1, CustomType2>`.
I create custom Serializer inherited from JsonSerializer.
I also create simple module and register it in my mapper;

```
SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule("myModule");
myModule.addKeySerializer(CustomType1.class, new CustomType1Serializer());
myModule.addSerializer(CustomType1.class, new CustomType1Serializer());
mapperInstance.registerModule(myModule);
```

And when I just serializing an instance of CustomType1 it works perfectly, but when I creating map and trying to serialize it, than jackson skip my serializer and using `StdKeySerializer`. **How to fix that???**

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem seems related to Jackson's handling of generic objects. One way to get around the issue is by using a super type token to strictly define the map type. Illustrated:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("myModule",
        Version.unknownVersion());
module.addKeySerializer(CustomType1.class, new CustomType1Serializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

final MapType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
        Map.class, CustomType1.class, CustomType2.class);
final Map<CustomType1, CustomType2> map = new HashMap<CustomType1, CustomType2>(4);
final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithType(type);
final String json = writer.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Comment: Very appriciate for your help =)

Answer (score 2):

addSerializer and addKeySerializer are just two types of available serializers that deal only with simple, non-POJO types. To have custom serialization for more complex types such as maps and collections, you need to .setSerializerModifier on your module, with a BeanSerializerModifier that overrides the modifyMapSerializer method and returns your custom serializer